# Need help with this Bayesian Network problem?

Tags: probability, bayesian, bayesian-network

[image: Problem]

From the problem above, is P(X|Y) not possible to determined since we are not given P(Y)? I've been stuck with this for days. Please give me some hints.

Btw, from the given information, we have P(Y|X) = 0.6/0.4 = 1.5 --> is it not wrong to have a probability greater than 1.0 ?

Comment: The problem states $P(Y\mid X)=0.4.$ How, then, do you derive $1.5$ for that value?  It looks like you might have a typographical error somewhere.

Comment: @whuber Oh how stupid I am. All solved. Thanks.